# How to translate the verb "to overlap" (w.r.t. meaning of words)?

Tags: single-word-requests

How to translate "overlap" in a sentence like the following?

> The meanings of these two words greatly overlap.

Answer (score 2):

En tiu kunteksto vi povus ekzmple diri:

```
Tiuj du vortoj kunhavas preskaŭ la samajn signifojn.
```

aŭ

```
La signifoj de tiuj du vortoj estas preskaŭ (plejparte) samaj.
```